# jQuery Saving different texts in the same tag extracted using jquery filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jQuery and I would like to know how to save/access separately each extracted word from the filter function.

```
var str="<b>I'm</b> a great <b>chef</b>.";
var extract=$(str).filter('b').text();
alert(extract);

//Output: I'm chef
```

I want to store in a different variables the **I'm** and **chef**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.eq()` for accessing the element collection,

```
var str="<b>I'm</b> a great <b>chef</b>.";
var extract=$(str).filter('b');
var var1 = extract.eq(0).text(); //I'm
var var2 = extract.eq(1).text(); //chef
```

Or you can extract those values in an array like,

```
var arr = extract.map(function(){ return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

Comment: Remove the `text()` method from `$(str).filter('b').text();`. Otherwise its not working *by the way, im not the downvoter :S*

Comment: @Nano Oh.. nice catch.. That was a typo.!